# What's wrong with these function's queries?

Tags: php, sql-server, function

I'd like to ask what's wrong with `SELECT Class, Race ......` query below. It triggers the `DB_ERROR`

```
$db = $this->database[GDB];
$character = $this->site->SanitizeName($_POST['character']);
$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT bNation FROM ACCOUNT_CHAR WHERE strAccountID = ? AND ? IN(strCharID1, strCharID2, strCharID3)', $_SESSION['strAccountID'], $character);
if ($num_rows == -1)
{
    $db->GetError(__file__, __line__);
    $this->m_ccError = Template::GetLangVar('DB_ERROR');
    return false;
}
else if ($num_rows == 0)
{
    $this->m_ccError = Template::GetLangVar('CC_INVALID_ACCOUNT');
    return false;
}

$row = $db->doRead();
$nation = $row['bNation'];

$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT Class, Race, Strong, Sta, Dex, Intel, Cha, Points, TransferTime FROM USERDATA u LEFT JOIN PREMIUM_SERVICE p ON p.strAccountID = ? WHERE strUserId = ? AND (TransferTime < IF(p.strAccountID IS NULL, DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()), DATEADD(MINUTE,-30,GETDATE())) OR TransferTime IS NULL) AND zone<>199 and authority<>255', $_SESSION['strAccountID'], $character);
if ($num_rows == -1)
{
    $db->GetError(__file__, __line__);
    $this->m_ccError = Template::GetLangVar('DB_ERROR');
    return false;
}
else if ($num_rows == 0)
{
    $this->m_ccError = Template::GetLangVar('CC_RECENT_TRANSFER');
    return false;
}
```

If I use this below, it works good. I added premium check, so check the last one below which doesn't want to work correctly.

```
$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT Class, Race, Strong, Sta, Dex, Intel, Cha, Points, TransferTime FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = ? AND (TransferTime < DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()) OR TransferTime IS NULL) and zone<>199 and authority<>255', $character);
```

but if I use this one below .. It triggers the `$num_rows == -1` and show the `DB_ERROR` from the main function above.

```
$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT Class, Race, Strong, Sta, Dex, Intel, Cha, Points, TransferTime FROM USERDATA u LEFT JOIN PREMIUM_SERVICE p ON p.strAccountID = ? WHERE strUserId = ? AND (TransferTime < IF(p.strAccountID IS NULL, DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()), DATEADD(MINUTE,-30,GETDATE())) OR TransferTime IS NULL) AND zone<>199 and authority<>255', $_SESSION['strAccountID'], $character);
```

I use MSSQL Server 2005 if that counts.
I will really appreciate any responses.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of *if then else* use **CASE WHEN**

   ((TransferTime < 
   CASE WHEN p.strAccountID IS NULL 
   THEN DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE())  ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE,-30,GETDATE()) END) 
   OR TransferTime IS NULL)
2. Also fully qualify your Select Clause to avoid ambiguous column problem. Try something like

   SELECT u.Class, u.Race, u.Strong, u.Sta, u.Dex, u.Intel, u.Cha, u.Points, u.TransferTime
3. Also your ON clause looks iffy.

Comment: I use this and again the error is triggered. `.... FROM USERDATA u LEFT JOIN PREMIUM_SERVICE p ON p.strAccountID = ? WHERE strUserID = ? AND ((TransferTime < CASE WHEN p.strAccountID IS NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE())  ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE,-30,GETDATE()) END) OR TransferTime IS NULL) AND zone<>199 and authority<>255', $_SESSION['strAccountID'], $character);` Also, take a note that I use MSSQL Server 2005 if this is supported ..

Comment: I believe the `PREMIUM_SERVICE`  - `JOIN` part isn't correct ?

Comment: Please suggest me how the ON clause should be. I will appreciate it a lot. I believe the problem is coming from there.

Comment: Without knowing your database, I am shooting in dark. Try something like `ON p.strAccountID = u.strUserId and u.strUserID = ?`

Comment: `strUserId` is character id and `strAccountID` is account id. So, premium is counted on account id. What I need to show you else ? To sum it up what I want to do is check if this account has premium, so he can class change his character id. Thats why just like my very first query from the function which checks for the nation, I can use the session to get the account id for this one, or its still iffy ? Please check my first one `SELECT bNation ...` from above and let me know. I am greatly appreciating your help.

Comment: Table `USERDATA` has only the character id, and `PREMIUM_SERVICE` has the account id.

Comment: Is the Class same as CharacterID? Also can you post sample data from two tables? If possible show what is your desired output?

Comment: @oLdPkj Also test your query first in SQL Server Mgmt Studio (SSMS) before putting it into your PHP code.

Comment: All SELECT statements are options for the character. It's like what hair, what color, what class (mage,rogue ..), so they are different. It checks if the character information is provided before it proceed to class change. But I added ON clause to check if their account is premium, so they can class change every 30 minutes instead of 2 days for normals. I hope you understand me what I mean. Why my ON clause looks iffy when my very first query use the `session strAccountID` as you can see above in my first post ? Can you let me know why it's iffy ?